# Where do I find a factory in Reassembly?

Tags: reassembly

I cannot seem to find a factory in the game Reassembly. Do I unlock it somehow? All I can find in my upgrade menu are resources that have come from plants and such.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, you will need to unlock the Factory in the Upgrade menu ('U').  Then, you'll need to add a Factory block to your ship.  Next, in order to pick what ships to spawn from the Factory, edit your fleet ('3').
Once you have enough purple Resources, you'll be able to spawn new ships with F.